# When is dbcontext disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, dispose

I create contructor where i create new dbcontext and then pass it to the another object.

```
private readonly Class1 _object1;
private readonly Class2 _object2;

public Service()
{
     DbContext context = new DbContext ();
     object1= new Class1(context);
     _object2= new Class2(context);
}
```

When will it be disposed? Will it be useful till the end of life my Service?
Is it any difference when i create another field for DbContext?

```
private readonly Dbcontext _context;
public Service()
{
    _context = new DbContext ();
    _object1= new Class1(_context);
    _object2= new Class2(_context);
}
```

Comment: Don't do this.. Either inject as scoped for a short lived service or controller, or use a `using` statement. Don't try and cache a `DbContext` you will create yourself all sorts of problems

Comment: Does this help you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/is-it-ok-to-create-an-entity-framework-datacontext-object-and-dispose-it-in-a-us#:~:text=Don't%20dispose%20DbContext%20objects,the%20database%20connection%20for%20you.

Comment: When the GC (garbage collection) removes the item.  Does not continuously run so items are disposed when the GC method runs (like a background task).  To force GC to execute you can wrap you code with a using block and GS will be called when you exit the using block.

Comment: @jdweng The `using` block does not cause GC ro run. The `using` block calls `Dispose` [on the object directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#remarks).

Comment: I agree GSerg. Disposing has nothing to do with the GC. It´s just a means for **un**managed resources, that can´t be handled by GC.

Comment: So, should i wrap it inside the using statement inside the constructor?

Comment: @marmite That depends on what your Class1 and Class2 do. If they only use the context in their constructors, then yes, do that. If they cache it for later use, then no, but then you should probably revise your approach. Data contexts are supposed to be lightweight objects to be created when needed.

Comment: @GSerg I have a lot of services which change database object and i would like to save it in one transaction. Till now i created one common _context which was passed to the all services and after invoking methods I invoked _context.SaveChanges();

Comment: When i was using Dependency Injection i used to pass DbContext to the contructor and then save it as a field for later using in class methods. Is it any different?

Comment: @marmite Then it looks like you can dispose it where you call SaveChanges, and your other classes should not cache it, and accept the context in each method where it's needed instead. Alternatively, you can switch to TransactionScope and just create contexts in each class separately, but then it will be promoted to a distributed transaction.